# Why does awk do full buffering when reading from a pipe

Tags: awk, tty, serial-port

I'm reading from a serial port connected to a gps device sending nmea strings.

A simplified invocation to illustrate my point:

```
  $ awk '{ print $0 }' /dev/ttyPSC9 
  GPGGA,073651.000,6310.1043,N,01436.1539,E,1,07,1.0,340.2,M,33.3,M,,0000*56
  $GPGSA,A,3,28,22,09,27,01,19,17,,,,,,2.3,1.0,2.0*39
  $GPRMC,073651.000,A,6310.1043,N,01436.1539,E,0.42,163.42,070312,,,A*67
  GPGGA,073652.000,6310.1043,N,01436.1540,E,1,07,1.0,339.2,M,33.3,M,,0000*55
  $GPGSA,A,3,28,22,09,27,01,19,17,,,,,,2.3,1.0,2.0*39
```

If I instead try to read from a pipe, awk buffers the input before sending it to stdout.

```
$ cat /dev/ttyPSC9 | awk '{ print $0 }'
<long pause>
GPGGA,073651.000,6310.1043,N,01436.1539,E,1,07,1.0,340.2,M,33.3,M,,0000*56
$GPGSA,A,3,28,22,09,27,01,19,17,,,,,,2.3,1.0,2.0*39
$GPRMC,073651.000,A,6310.1043,N,01436.1539,E,0.42,163.42,070312,,,A*67
GPGGA,073652.000,6310.1043,N,01436.1540,E,1,07,1.0,339.2,M,33.3,M,,0000*55
$GPGSA,A,3,28,22,09,27,01,19,17,,,,,,2.3,1.0,2.0*39
```

How can I avoid the buffering?

**Edit**: Kyle Jones suggested that cat is buffering it's output but that doesn't appear to be happening:

```
$ strace cat /dev/ttyPSC9 | awk '{ print $0 }'
write(1, "2,"..., 2)                    = 2
read(3, "E"..., 4096)                   = 1
write(1, "E"..., 1)                     = 1
read(3, ",0"..., 4096)                  = 2
```

When I think about it: I thought that a program used line buffering when writing to a terminal and "regular buffering" for all other cases. Then, why is cat not buffering more? Is the serial port signalling EOF? Then why is cat not terminated?

My `awk` is mawk 1.2.

Comment: [BashFAQ 009](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/009) may be useful.

Comment: @jw013: Thanks for the link, a great sum up of how buffering works in bash.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is likely to be buffering in awk, not cat. In the first case, awk believes it is interactive because its input and output are TTYs (even though they're different TTYs - I'm guessing that awk is not checking that). In the second, the input is a pipe so it runs non-interactively.

You will need to explicitly flush in your awk program. This is not portable, though.

For more background and details on how to flush output, read: http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/I_002fO-Functions.html

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. `awk -W interactive '{print $0}'` appears to do the trick. The `'W interactive` option is available on my awk version (mawk 1.2) but I dunno if it's a standard option.

Comment: @dannas `-W` is not in the [POSIX standard for `awk`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html).  I'm not sure what to do if you need maximum portability.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer since it explains why awk is doing full buffering in my example, instead of line buffering - it checks the if the input is a tty as well as the output. I only thought that it would check the output.

Comment: @jw013: Thanks for looking up the standard. For me, I just wanted to understand why awk was doing full buffering and I think I do now.

Comment: @dannas I can confirm that `-W interactive` is at least supported in the Ubuntu 12.04 (and presumably newer) distribution of awk, which is mawk.

Comment: After much searching this answered my query as to why my pipe after `awk` was not getting input. I followed the link to the gawk documentation and ended up using `fflush("/dev/stdout")` which solved my issue.

Answer (score 61):

I know it is an old question, but a one-liner may help those who come here searching:

```
cat /dev/ttyPSC9 | awk '{ print $0; system("")}'
```

`system("")` does the trick, and is POSIX compliant. Non-posix systems: beware.

There exists a more specific function `fflush()` that does the same, but is not available in older versions of awk.

An important piece of information from [the docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/I_002fO-Functions.html#index-sidebar_002c-Controlling-Output-Buffering-with-system_0028_0029) regarding the use of `system("")`:

> gawk treats this use of the system() function as a special case and is
>   smart enough not to run a shell (or other command interpreter) with
>   the empty command. Therefore, with gawk, this idiom is not only
>   useful, it is also efficient.

Comment: This worked for me

Comment: My `awk` doesn't do anything on neither `fflush()` nor `system("")`. My `gawk` honored it though.

Comment: This worked on Mac's `awk version 20200816` from Mac OS Ventura, thank god.

Answer (score 5):

Old topic but maybe worth to add one more solution which changes stream buffering behavior in a transparent way without some magic like `system("")` :-)

```
cat /dev/ttyPSC9 | stdbuf --output=L awk '{print $0}'
```

Used it myself recently to catch a D-Bus event.

```
gdbus monitor -y -d org.freedesktop.login1 | stdbuf -oL  grep LockedHint
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my problem on RHEL 7.