# `cat /dev/ttyACM` loses data when piped through netcat

Tags: networking, pipe, hardware, tcp, raspberry-pi

I'm reading data from `/dev/ttyACM0` using `cat /dev/ttyACM0` on a Raspberry Pi. The data comes from a device, which sends lines in the form

```
15.00   1316013 15
```

where the first number is a value, the second a millisecond timestamp from the device.

When I do `cat /dev/ttyACM0 > file.csv` I receive one value every 12~13ms, but when I do the exact same thing over the network, I get a 1~2 second gap every 5 seconds.

Is it possible that there is lost data somewhere? Or that the OS blocks the serial device so it has to wait a couple of seconds to send more data? Is there any relation between a serial device and a piped network command?

I'm using either `netcat` or `ssh` to pipe the data. The device is sending data at 9600 bps

Comment: Some of the links at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33650/why-does-awk-do-full-buffering-when-reading-from-a-pipe may help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out `cat /dev/ttyACM0 | awk` is not exactly the same as `</dev/ttyACM awk`

And awk does buffering too, as cpugeniusmv commented.